# How to convert NSScanner value to string?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, int, nsscanner

hi guys can you tell me how get the value from NSScanner in a string?
infect i have to extract int value from a string i am extracting it using scanner now my value is in scanner. now how to get that value?

```
NSString *string = @" rate 50%";
    int n;
        NSScanner * scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:string];
        [scanner scanInt:&n];
```

now where is my value and how to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with NSScanner in your instance.

Give this a go.

```
    NSString *string = @" rate 50%";
    NSString *digits = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                        [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
    NSLog(@"Value: %i", [digits intValue]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Lee that you needn't bother with NSScanner in your example. But in your example, the int `n` is set to 50. That's why you pass the address of `n` to `scanInt`–so `scanInt` can change its value.